# How to install nltk 2.0.4 module in Python using get-pip.py in a Windows machine?

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, nltk

I have Python 2.7 installed and I want to use get-pip.py to install the nltk module (version2.0.4) onto a windows machine.

```
python get-pip.py nltk-2.0.4
python get-pip.py nltk 2.0.4
```

ran on command line and did not work. Complained about not able to find distributions matching "nltk 2.0.4" This has to be version 2.0.4 and not version 3.0 (the most updated one). Does anyone know how to download specific versions of modules using get-pip.py on windows machine?

Comment: why you dont use `sudo pip install -U nltk` ?

Comment: @Kasra its a windows OS...

Comment: @Kasramvd because the book uses version 2.0.4 and the current V3 (default) version has many inconsistencies with the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to install packages in windows with python

```
python -m pip install package
```

For your case use

```
python -m pip install nltk==2.0.4
```